# Usar aplicação feita em VB6 em um smartwatch

Tags: android, sql-server, visual-basic-6

É possível criar uma aplicação para o *smartwatch* no qual a aplicação já está feita em Visual Basic e tem a BDA em SQL Server? O objetivo é o utilizador poder ver os dados no *smartwatch* como por exemplo num *dashboard* normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se vai criar, ela não está feita. Se já está feita, não vai criar.

Não foi dito qual é o dispositivo, mas nenhum deles roda VB6, ele é dependente do Windows completo e só existem alguns poucos dispositivos bem maiores que rodam o Windows completo.

Mesmo que possa vir acontecer a linguagem não seria adequada para aproveitar os recursos do dispositivo. Mais ainda, se está feita, foi pensando em tela grande e usando recursos de um computador "normal", não ficaria bom.

Então essa ideia não faz sentido.

Sugiro ver quais as linguagens disponíveis para ele - se roda Android pode ser Java, C# (é possível que até rode VB.NET, mas não sei se de forma ideal), e outras - estudá-la em profundidade, entender as diferenças para desenvolver para este tipo de dispositivo e criar o cliente.

É possível, dependendo de como foi desenvolvido o lado do servidor, aproveitar essa parte, mas duvido. Não posso afirmar, não sei de nada o que foi feito, mas quem fazia VB6 não criava aplicações para servidor. Acessar o banco de dados direto está fora de cogitação. Terá que criar um servidor de aplicação. Alguns optarão por uma aplicação comunicação por TCP, mas a maioria fará algo por HTTP, o que não quer dizer que é a melhor decisão.

Enfim, é o que dá para responder.

Comment: Boas, obrigado pela resposta! Respondendo, a aplicação está criada em vb.net com ligação bda sql server no qual mostra a nivel web(site), o dashboard(php) o relatório dos campos que eu estou interessado em mostrar. A minha duvida é qual a melhor maneira mostrar uma espécie de dashboard também mas para o smartwatch, sendo assim é melhor usar outra linguagem como Java ou C#?

Comment: Muito provavelmente, mas a melhor para seu caso só você pode responder.